# FocusListener on Tabs/ScaleImageLabel

Tags: codenameone

I've added ScaleImageLabel to swipe Tabs. I want to calculate amount of time each tab remains in focus. I added focus listener to Tabs/ScaleImageLabel but it's not getting fired. It's working when added to the form. Any suggestions on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need is a tab selection listener. Focus listener will only work for focusable components and labels are by default non-focusable. I would recommend avoiding it since focus is used for key based navigation. It might produce different results than you would expect.